# Failed to compile JSP in weblogic 12c. Class method undefined

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic12c, jsp-tags

I am trying to call a Java class method from JSP. But I am getting the below error:

> <[ServletContext@511217905[app:MyWAR module:abcd
>   path:null spec-version:3.1]] Root cause of ServletException.
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP
>   /something.jsp something.jsp:224:169: The method method_name(String)
>   is undefined for the type Classname

*I have the Java class and method present and compiled and build correctly.
I have also deployed the application in my weblogic server withpout any issues. 
Now I am trying to use one functionality in my application by clicking a button and I am getting this error.
I am using Java 1.8 and Weblogic 12c.*

This is my JSP :

```
<%@page import="com.xyz.zaq.web.utils.Classname"%>
<% if(!allowmod) { %>
<td align="right"><%=SystemStrings.getParam6()%></td>
    <%
            if (!allowmod) {
    %>
    <td><input type="text" size="60" maxlength="255"
            onkeypress="validateInputLength(this, 'P_A', event)" name="param6"
            value="<%=Classname.encode(Classname.method_name(p6))%>"
            readonly="readonly"></td>
    <%
        } else {
    %>
    <td><input type="text" size="60" maxlength="255"
            onkeypress="validateInputLength(this, 'P_A', event)" name="param6"
            value="<%=Classname.encode(p6)%>" readonly="readonly"></td>
    <%
        }
    %>
```

StackTrace :

```
something.jsp:294:167: The method method_name(String) is undefined for the type Classname
<td><input type="text" size="60" maxlength="255" onkeypress="validateInputLength(this, 'P_A', event)" name="param10" value="<%=Classname.encode(Classname.method_name(p10))%>"
readonly="readonly"></td>^M


        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.reportCompilationErrorIfNeccessary(JavelinxJSPStub.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage0(JavelinxJSPStub.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.access$000(JavelinxJSPStub.java:50)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub$1.run(JavelinxJSPStub.java:111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage(JavelinxJSPStub.java:108)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:267)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:218)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.getServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:414)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:304)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:489)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:376)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3702)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3672)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:328)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1705)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1665)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Please let me know what I am missing out.

Comment: Is your `method_name` static? can you show its signature? also what's `p6`?

Comment: Yes its a static method.

Comment: @user7294900  :  Yes its a static method. p6 is just a parameter which is a string that I am passing on to the method. method signature is :

JSP Code : `String p6 = javaction.getParm6();`

 Java Code :    `public static String method_name(String s)`